# Concatenate string with another that contains a variable

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL query in Python using MySQLdb that I want to give me a different number of rows depending on if there is a LIMIT provided or not.

So, something like:

```
sql = "SELECT URL, Name AS Category 
       FROM sitelist sl 
       INNER JOIN sitecategory sc ON sc.PlacementCategory_id = sl.Category_id "
if limit > 0 :
    sql += "LIMIT %s", (limit)
```

However, this fails:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

**How would I be able to concatenate the string containing the `limit` number while keeping the query 'safe'?** In the case of the above being an individual string, the above works correctly.

In PHP, I would simply use a prepared PDO statement with `bindparam()`, but I cannot find anything similar in Python.

Comment: In your case: use `"LIMIT %d" % limit`!

Comment: Is that safe to use in an SQL query, though? I had seen some other answers and results that indicated it would not be.

Comment: `%d` is limited to integers, no harmful character is contained in them. Of cause you must not use `%s`.

Comment: If you have problem with quoting complex queries you can also consider using a ORM like SQLAlchemy which will do all the tricks for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the neatest way to do this is:

```
sql = ("SELECT URL, Name AS Category "
       "FROM sitelist sl "
       "INNER JOIN sitecategory sc ON sc.PlacementCategory_id = sl.Category_id")

if limit > 0:
    whatever.execute(sql+" LIMIT %s", (limit,))
else:
    whatever.execute(sql)
```

Note that: `sql` should have opening and closing quotes on every line; and `limit` needs to be in a tuple as an argument to `execute`.

Answer (score -1):

use `string` formatting.

```
sql = "SELECT URL, Name AS Category\n\
   FROM sitelist sl\n\
   INNER JOIN sitecategory sc ON sc.PlacementCategory_id = sl.Category_id "
if limit > 0: # you don't need parenthesis in python
    sql += "LIMIT {}" .format(limit)
```

or use `format specifier`.

```
sql = "SELECT URL, Name AS Category\n\
       FROM sitelist sl\n\
       INNER JOIN sitecategory sc ON sc.PlacementCategory_id = sl.Category_id "
if(limit > 0):
    sql += "LIMIT %d" %limit
```

Comment: The OP is specific about wanting to keep the query safe, which interpolating the `limit` value (which could be anything) doesn't do

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think query is safe now.